# How to use Rails Devise with another REST authentication service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have a central server that provides basic REST endpoints for registering, login, logout. How do I integrate this seamlessly with my Rails application using Devise?

EDIT: I'm provided a REST API which basically tells me if a user/password combo is correct or not. I want Devise to hook up to this API instead of using local DB strategy, kinda like how Devise hooks up to OmniAuth. My situation is very similar to this guy [Remote API Authentication With Rails 3 Using ActiveResource and Devise](http://blog.codebykat.com/2012/07/23/remote-api-authentication-with-rails-3-using-activeresource-and-devise/) except I don't use ActiveResource and the authentication API doesn't return a token.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Basic authentication is implemented by `Devise`, so the only code required is a call to `authenticate_user!` in your corresponding controller.

See this: [How To: Use HTTP Basic Authentication](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-HTTP-Basic-Authentication) 
and
[How To: Use HTTP Auth Basic with Devise](http://How%20To:%20Use%20HTTP%20Auth%20Basic%20with%20Devise)
for more information.

Comment: hellocrowley, did my answer help? Let me know if you have any other question!

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer. My usecase is more complex than that. I'm provided a REST API which basically tells me if a user/password combo is correct or not. I want Devise to hook up to this API like how Devise hooks up to OmniAuth, so I can leverage its helpers and session management. My situation is very similar to this guy: http://blog.codebykat.com/2012/07/23/remote-api-authentication-with-rails-3-using-activeresource-and-devise/ except I don't use ActiveResource.

Comment: I just learned about custom authentication strategy, will try to post a solution if it works..